# Heroku, sinatra & carrierwave. Doesn't load Carrierwave in the first place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sinatra, carrierwave

I'm getting quite a strange error on heroku. Sometimes when I deploy my app it says `uninitialized constant Page::PagePreviewUploader (NameError)` like I just don't have Carrierwave gem included... If I restart the app 1-5 times with `heroku restart` it starts to work correctly. And sometimes it just works fine after 1st attempt.

I have a feeling that heroku loads files in a random order so on one try it loads carrierwave gem first, on another - is starts with the other files and I get that error... Why? How to load carrierwave first every time?

I have carrierwave in my gem file and that's how it's included

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
require 'sinatra'
#....some other gems....
require 'carrierwave'
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord' 


Bundler.setup(:default, LAC.environment)

#Load all the other files in config, models etc.
[:config, :models, :helpers, :routes].each do |dir|
      Dir[File.join(dir.to_s, '*')].each do |file|
        send(:require, './'+file) unless File.directory? file
      end
end
```